# NextIdentityFor missing

Tags: c#, ravendb, ravendb4

This question pertains to 4th version of RavenDb only. 
With previous versions we had an option to generate Identity Key for a collection viz.

```
 _documentStore.DatabaseCommands.NextIdentityFor(collectionName);
```

How do I do the same in RavenDb 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In RavenDB 4.0, this is now done as:

```
using (var shortTermSingleUse = JsonOperationContext.ShortTermSingleUse())
{
    var command = new NextIdentityForCommand("users");
    await store.GetRequestExecutor().ExecuteAsync(command, shortTermSingleUse);
}
```

Comment: I had a question for distributed architecture. I know RavenDb4 now supports distributed architecture by design. Will the ids generated, by technique mentioned above be unique across databases? I have read about the allotment of range of Id(s) to every instance, so I am hoping answer is yes.

Comment: Yes, in this manner, this is done as a cluster operation and ensure that you have a value that is unique cluster wide for this database.